# send data from child1 to child2 over parent

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, use-state, react-context, react-state

I have this (simplified) structure in my React app:

```
      App
       |
   ---------
   |       |
Child1   Child2
```

I want to pass the data from `Child1` to `Child2` (for example clicking button in `Child1` will change colour of one element in `Child2`)

Two important points here:

1. I want to **avoid Redux** if possible
2. I don't want to re-render the whole app. Only **`Child2` should re-render**

Is there any option how to achieve that (without Redux)?

Comment: I'd say the react context API is the way to go here, anything other than that will become harder to read and maintain IMO

Comment: @placementw thanks, but how would that be achieved with only Context API (keeping the points from question)?

Comment: You create a context, wrap the two components with the Provider(one provider should wrap both), and you export the data from the provider, that way, every component inside the provider will be able to access that data, including the 2 children

Comment: @placementw That way I have it now (state is in the App component), but this re-renders the whole app. What I want is to re-render only the Child2 by interaction in Child1. Here I think I can't use Context API for that. So I might need to use Redux, but just wanted to know if there is a better/more lightweight solution.

Comment: to avoid the unnecessary re-renders, I'd probably look into React memo, seems like it would solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to make each child "dumb" and just have them just present the UI. Anything that changes causes side effects (state changes / handling clicks, etc) is moved up to the parent element, and into a hook.

Child1 gets an onClick function (from the parent via the hook) and child2 gets whatever state variables affect its appearance.

If the children are within other children and you want to avoid "prop drilling", then using React.Context is lightweight.

Comment: if I make the state to change in the parent, wouldn't it then re-render the whole App and thus child1 and child2? I might have it like that right now (but the truth is that this state contains preferences for the whole app, which might be the issue here) and the app re-render takes quite a long time (time between click and changes happens)

Comment: React may re-render from the parent down (which may be everything in your example) but it's fairly lightweight if the component's parameters don't change, and even lighter if the Dom doesn't actually need to be updated. You can memoize things to reduce rendering and computation and wrap functions passed to components in useCallback, etc if you really do need to optimize. You could look at Zustand, which is lightweight way to pass state around. Need to pick your battles... Try the above. Turn on debug mode to show which components re-render. Try something else if it's too expensive.